# how does c++ template work in when we use libs?

Tags: c++, compilation

I firstly think c++ compiler like g++ generates different functions or classes for different templates in compiling stage, But when we use a lib, lib binary has been made, it has been a fixed binary, just for link, why template still works?

Comment: Unless the templates are fully defined in the header files it wont work

Answer (score 3):

When you use a library, you `#include` its header files. The logic for a templated function/class is in the header file. This allows the compiler to generate the concrete implementations.